# How do I execute this SublimeREPL shortcut

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimerepl

How do I execute this shortcut?  What key combination is that?  I don't get what ",," means.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> at the same time, release them, then press <kbd>s</kbd>.

Comment: So one `,` is for keyboard key <>kbd>,<kbd> and other for , punctuation ? Nice I didn't know this ..

Comment: Yes, right.  The keymap sequence really doesn't look 'right' as it is displayed in the drop down menu.  In case you or anyone else is interested, you can check the package's `.sublime-keymap` file and find the sequence in a much more friendly syntax:  `{ "keys": ["ctrl+,", "s"], "command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "selection"}},`